# Is there a pre_post_title hook in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've seen various references across the web to a `pre_post_title` hook in WordPress. I've searched the code base but cannot find it in any file. I've also seen references to `pre_post_content`

Are these actual hooks? If so, which WordPress core file will I find them in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you even search for available [Wordpress hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks)?

Comment: I even did! Nothing found. I also did a search on the full WordPress code base but nothing. Perhaps these were once hooks but have been removed? Not sure myself. I was confused because if you Google them, lots of people seem to be using them in their code examples.

Comment: I've never heard about these hooks, but apparently they really exist ([see line 2012 in post.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/post.php)).

Comment: Aha! pre_post_{$field} - that explains why my search for pre_post_content returned nothing. Thanks for your help lars-beck.

Answer (score 0):

That is a dynamic hook (`pre_{$field}`) that is generated in the [sanitize_post_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_post_field/) method.